# Why it can't render html file in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

skills_app = Flask(__name__)

@skills_app.route("/")
    def homepage():
        return render_template("homepage.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    skills_app.run()
```

Now homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello from Html page
</body>
</html>
```

but when I run my page,"Hello from HTML page" doesn't show up
and yes i created templates folder and put homepage.html inside it.
so what is the problem here? could you help me

Comment: What you mean by *run my page*?

Comment: I mean run the python file, then i click on the http://.............. , but "Hello From HTML page", doesn't show up on the page.

Comment: I don't know what a browser would do with that. Do you maybe want to put your text into a HTML tag? E.g.: `<p>Hello from Html page</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Flask looks for `templates` directory to render. If you want to make your code work, create a templates folder next to your main file, put homepage.html inside it.

Or, initialize app like,

```
skills_app = Flask(__name__, templates='/path/to/directory/containing/html-files')
```

and put your templates to the `/path/to/directory/containing/html-files`

Comment: i'm a beginner, so can show me how to put the templates in the /path/to/directory/containing/html-files

Comment: Create a `folder`. Then put your `homepage.html` inside that folder. Do not forget to update your `Flask` instance about that `folder`